# Iterate through cell values and conditional formatting

Tags: vba, loops, excel, conditional-statements

I have 10 cells in a column that are % error values. If any of the values are less than -0.1 or greater than 0.1, and if a certain drop down box is selected as "No", then I need an adjacent column to be unlocked and able to be edited.  What I have done is named the entire column of cells (Perc_Error1), and used that to reference... I think that is where the problem is, excel isn't reading each cell value but rather the whole name value and it probably has no idea what it is..

I want to iterate through each % error cell value, but I also need to read the dropdown value as well.. this doesn't seem to be working with the code I have

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim i As Variant
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=TRPassword
    If Range("Annual_Verif").value = "Yes" Then
        Range("Ref_Test_Point").Locked = False
        Range("EGM_Target_Reading").Locked = True
        Range("EGM_Reading").Locked = False
        Range("Perc_Error2").Locked = True
        End If


    If (Range("Annual_Verif").value = "No") Then Resume Next
        For Each i In Range("Perc_Error1").Cells
            If (Abs(i.value) > (0.1)) Then
                Range("Ref_Test_Point").Locked = False
                Range("EGM_Target_Reading").Locked = True
                Range("EGM_Reading").Locked = False
                Range("Perc_Error2").Locked = True
            End If
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=TRPassword
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Where is the value from the drop-down box considered?

Is Perc_Error2 the adjacent column? 

What are the EGM_Target_Reading & EGM_Reading cells?

What is the result of this code, and why is it not working?

Comment: Drop down = "Annual_Verif".  All of the ranges that are locked= false are the adjacent columns.  I had the code in the wrong spot, I moved it to the specific worksheet change sub, but it is not unlocking those cells when the value is above 0.1.  I have edited my code above...

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the mixup of

> If any of the values are less than 0.1 or greater than -0.1

If you mean what your condition states, your

```
If (Abs(i.value) > (0.1)) Then
```

should be

```
If (Abs(i.value) < (0.1)) Then
```

If you mean "greater than" to mean a larger absoloute number, then your if statement should be

```
If i.value < 0.1 And i.value < -.1  Then
```

Comment: I wrote that wrong in my question and have edited it.. the restrictions are coded correctly I just miswrote it in my question